# Can't Get Telerik Legend to work with Bar Chart

Tags: uwp, telerik

I cannot get my legend to display anything other than the labels.  It will not show the color shapes.  The stacked bar chart does display correctly.  Could you please take a look at my XAML code, and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I've researched this extensively, and my code seems to match the examples that I have found online. Thanks.

```
        <telerikPrimitives:RadLegendControl LegendProvider="{Binding ElementName=BarChart}"                                           
                                        x:Name="legend"
                                        RelativePanel.Below="BarChart"
                                        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadLegendControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadLegendControl.ItemsPanel>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadLegendControl>

            <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart Name="BarChart" PaletteName="DefaultDark"  RelativePanel.Below="pieChart" Width="400" Height="400">
                <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                    <telerikChart:CategoricalAxis />
                </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                    <telerikChart:LinearAxis />
                </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                    <telerikChart:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="Y" StripLinesVisibility="Y" />
                </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                <telerikChart:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MyData, Mode=TwoWay}" CombineMode="Stack" LegendTitle="Ready" IsVisibleInLegend="True">
                    <telerikChart:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                        <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
                    </telerikChart:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                    <telerikChart:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                        <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Evaluator"/>
                    </telerikChart:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                </telerikChart:BarSeries>
                <telerikChart:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MyData2, Mode=TwoWay}" CombineMode="Stack" LegendTitle="Not Ready" IsVisibleInLegend="True">
                    <telerikChart:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                        <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
                    </telerikChart:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                    <telerikChart:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                        <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Evaluator"/>
                    </telerikChart:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                </telerikChart:BarSeries>
            </telerikChart:RadCartesianChart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue in a UWP app. By testing on my side, if you are using other series, for example, `PointSeries` or `AreaSeries`, the legend control will work well, only `BarSeries` have issues. So that there should be nothing wrong with your above code, this may be caused by something wrong with the package or not supported. You may open a new issue [here](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/issues).

As a workaround you could use the legend control in unbound mode. For a sample please reference [this](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radchart/legend-control/legendcontrol-unboundmode) to complete customization of the legend items.

Comment: Thanks Sunteen.  Also, please see Telerik's response and suggested workaround here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/legend-will-only-display-labels-(windows-10)